# Explaining MySQL query with multiple tables listed in FROM

Tags: mysql

a, b are not directly related.

What does a,b have to do with the results?

`select * from a,b where b.id in (1,2,3)`

can you explain sql?

Comment: **simply the sql says:** Get all the rows by joining the table `a` and `b` with a condition when `b.id` is equal to **either** `1 or 2 or 3`

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't specified a relationship between `a` and `b`, this produces a cross product. It's equivalent to:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
CROSS JOIN b
WHERE b.id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

It will combine every row in `a` with the three selected rows from `b`. If `a` has 100 rows, the result will be 300 rows.

Answer (score 1):

What you using is `Multitable SELECT`.

> `Multitable SELECT (M-SELECT)` is similar to the join operation. You
>   select values from different tables, use `WHERE` clause to limit the
>   rows returned and send the resulting single table back to the
>   originator of the query.
>
> The difference with `M-SELECT` is that it would return multiply tables
>   as the result set. 
>  For more deatils: https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=358

In other word, you query is :

```
SELECT * 
FROM a 
CROSS JOIN b 
WHERE b.id in (1,2,3)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I understand.

Comment: When you quote another site, you should include a link to the site.

Comment: What does it mean by "return multiply tables"? The result set is just a single table, although it includes rows from both original tables, but that's the same as any other join.

Comment: @Barmar reference link, agree. Will update my answer.

Comment: @Barmar "return multiply tables" simply means a cross join which is different from other join. It work similar to `inner join` when using `where` clause along with it.